# error with strptime() to extract date from timestamp with python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I try to extract hour from the timestamp :
I have a dataframe called df_no_missing :

```
df_no_missing.info()
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> Int64Index: 34673 entries, 1 to 43228
> Data columns (total 8 columns):
> TIMESTAMP        34673 non-null object
> P_ACT_KW         34673 non-null float64
> PERIODE_TARIF    34673 non-null object
> P_SOUSCR         34673 non-null float64
> SITE             34673 non-null object
> TARIF            34673 non-null object
> depassement      34673 non-null float64
> date             34673 non-null int64
> dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(4)
> memory usage: 2.4+ MB
> ```

This is my code :

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
mytime = datetime.strptime(df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print (mytime.day)
print (mytime.hour)
```

I get this error :

> in ()
>         1 df_no_missing.info()
>         2 from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>   ----> 3 mytime = datetime.strptime(df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
>         4 print (mytime.day)
>         5 print (mytime.hour)
>
> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: `df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"]` returns the whole column, you can't use it in this context. What do you expect the value of `mytime` to be?

Comment: This seems invalid, the column `dtype` is `object` suggesting it's string, you haven't displayed what the current format is but can you try `df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"] = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"])` to convert to `datetime` after which you can do `df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"].dt.day` and `df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"].dt.hour`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would probably want to use `datetime.strptime` on a single entry rather than on the dataframe object itself? Try something like:

```
for data in df_no_missing["TIMESTAMP"]:
    mytime = datetime.strptime(data,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    print (mytime.day)
    print (mytime.hour)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, and then To add a column "day" which contains the day dor each timestamp , I have to do :  df_no_missing['jour'] = mytime.day   ?

Comment: I guess something like: `df1['new_field'] = df1['some_field'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").day)` would do the trick, but check @EdChum comment as well